# Python - Time conversion in a loop through a .csv column

Tags: python, loops, csv, time

I've got a big .csv file with data stored from some recordings. One of the fields has the time in which recordings were made, and I need to do a conversion in order to operate with them later.

```
*Col 0, hh:mm:ss, col 2, col 3,...*
```

I know how to do the time conversion with a single value, it with a single value. This works,

```
import decimal
from datetime import datetime

time = "14:55:36.629"
(hour,min,sec) = time.split(':')
result = int(hour) * 3600 + int(min) * 60 + float(sec)
decimal.Decimal(result)
```

But I'm unable to insert it in a loop

```
with open('input.csv', 'r') as inf, open('output.csv','wb') as outf:
    for row in inf:
        t = row[1]
        (h,m,s) = row[1].split(':') # Error here
        result = int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + float(s)
        decimal.Decimal(result)
    outcsv = csv.writer(outf, delimiter=',')
```

I'm stuck with the conversion, although at the same time I'm not sure whether later I'd be able to write the info in the other file. How can I convert and parse all the values into a column?

It'd also be fine for me to write over the original file instead of opening another one and writing the info there.

Comment: You aren't reading the file as CSV - `row[1]` is *a single character*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution write in a different file the output. If you want to write on the same file, you need to load and process your input file as a list of rows, and then write to the the same file.

```
import csv
with open('input.csv', 'r') as inf, open('output.csv','wb') as outf:
    reader = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter=',' )
    for row in reader:
        t = row
        (h,m,s) = t[1].split(':')
        result = int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + float(s)
        t[1] = result
        writer.writerow(t)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but after the conversion, how should I write it into a list? I manage to write the initial info, but not after the operation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually read the input file [*as CSV*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). Compare and contrast, with some dummy data:

```
>>> demo = ['id,time,data', '1,14:17:33,7', '2,14:17:34,10']
```

Iterating over the "file" directly:

```
>>> for row in demo:
    row[1]


'd'
','
','
```

Iterating over it read as CSV:

```
>>> import csv
>>> for row in csv.reader(demo):
    row[1]


'time'
'14:17:33'
'14:17:34'
```

Or, to make your code clearer (assuming you do have a header row):

```
>>> for row in csv.DictReader(demo):
    row['time']


'14:17:33'
'14:17:34'
```